# Можно ли как-то делать автопостинг в VK API без иконки рядом с датой, которое ведет на standalone приложение?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли как то вызывать Vk API, чтобы такой иконки не появлялось?

Я ведь правильно понял, что автоматически делать посты в группе, можно только из standalone приложений? И не официальный вариант это private api.
+ еще можно отправлять запросы от имени офиц. приложений. Но иконка тогда все равно будет, только от этих официальных приложений.

Comment: Единственный способ постить без иконки — через браузер или прикидываться браузером

Comment: @andreymal
Ну этот способ обычно и называют private api.
Печально.

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться, чем вам иконка не угодила-то?)

Comment: @andreymal
Просто не хотелось, чтобы пользователи знали, что посты выставляются автоматически. Не люблю лишние детали :)

Answer (score 0):

Официальный ответ поддержки Vk:

> Здравствуйте, Yury!
>
> Нет, от иконки избавиться нельзя.
>
> Тёплого и солнечного лета!
>
> Команда поддержки ВКонтакте